# How can I select a string from the beginning until a specified character?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrange

How can I select a string from the beginning until a specified character?

For example, in the following a news headline...

`someString = @"Los Angeles, California - Apple announces something, stock prices change."`

How do I select just `Los Angeles, California -` into a separate string? (I want to base my selection on everything before the `-` ("dash") character.

**EDIT:**

Say my headline looks like this:

`someString = @"Los Angeles, California - Apple announces something - stock prices change."`

How do I prevent my location string from looking like this: `Los Angeles, California - Apple announces something`?

**Edit:**

My mistake, I was removing the first dash and then reprising the string. My mistake the posted answer works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
NSRange rangeOfDash = [someString rangeOfString:@"-"];
substring = (rangeOfDash.location != NSNotFound) ? [someString substringToIndex:rangeOfDash.location] : nil;
```

This sets the `substring` to `nil` if there's no dash in the `someString`.

Comment: What would rangeOfDash be based on someString after parsing the whole thing?

Comment: I only want the first dash, not subsequent dashes. see my edit.